# BizTalk DB cluster Master DB get corrupted

Tags: biztalk

I have an issue that the DB cluster crashed and the master db is corrupted, the DB admin rebuild the master DB and restore the other databases and now the cluster is up and running, but the BizTalk configurations are lost. any idea how to retrieve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only the master, or any other System Database, was corrupted, then the BizTalk Databases, BizTalkMbmetDb etc. should be ok, just not attached.

Your DB admin should have taken care to reattach all the databases to the new/repaired SQL instance.

If the SQL Server and Instance name are the same, BizTalk should just start up again.

If they names are different, then you will have to reconfigure the BizTalk Host Computers to point to the new SQL Server.